# Flutter: Use of custom graphics (texture atlas)

Tags: flutter

Goal: Using 9patches/texture atlas/svg with flutter. 
Flutter tries to look native on both android and iOS. 
What if I want to create e.g. a button with the shape and texture I created. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not saying that anything is stopping me from doing so. I was researching and did not find any clear answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m sorry not to know about svg. But I can tell you how to use 9patches with a image.

1. Use Container
2. Set BoxDecoration to decoration property in Container
3. Set DecoratedImage with a image in BoxDecoration
4. Set Rect to centerSlice property in BoxDecoration

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/DecorationImage/centerSlice.html

I hope this will help you!!